# JQueryUI need event to fire after clicked tab is done animating and visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I need to be able to detect when a JQuery tab as been clicked and the tab contents is fully visible.  I've tried the activate event, which states:

> Triggered after a tab has been activated (after animation completes).

However, in my testing, this event fires before the tab contents are made visible. I have some code that needs to run once the tab is visible becasue it is dependent on determining the height and width of the div.

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ){
        alert("here");
        //do stuff here based on the size of the now visible tab
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aoxemxjk/

The alert is displayed before the tab content is displayed.

I've tried the load event, but that doesn't even fire.

Comment: your fiddle does not reflect your mentioned issue. it works fine there. It may be because of the lack of animation (as mentioned in your question). So please add any animation (that is triggered per tab switch) you want to your fiddle to at least help us reproduce the issue you have.

Comment: Note that you cannot rely on `alert` to test the order of code execution. It's some kind of how javascript works. I mean anything changing the UI rendering (even if done before calling `alert`) won't take effect right away while the alert is shown right after that (and still being shown). You can test this easily like this: https://jsfiddle.net/h9sbqs95/

Comment: @King.  THe animation I'm referring to (I assume) is simply the animation of displaying the tab.  I didn't know that about alerts.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("here");
            //do stuff here based on the size of the now visible tab
        });
    }
});
```